# Nuxt Universal Mode not helping with vue meta

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-meta

i am using nuxt for my application and have default mode i.e. universal mode. As i needed to make support of meta tags. But even though i have ssr mode and i can see ssr thing when inspecting the page, it’s picking up default meta description, image etc instead of dynamic one that i have mentioned in different pages.

As visible in below image i have hid mentioned too, to avoid duplication, but it still picks the one which is the default in config file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're a little confuse

Nuxt offers [3 ways to manage meta tags](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo/). You can set global on nuxt.config **OR** locally as object **OR** locally as function.

You should delete the global configuration before use meta tags at local (pages) level